# Why is path.name() in python 3.4 giving me "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"?

Tags: python, path, typeerror, python-3.4

The following code is just trying to print the name of all files in a directory:

```
from pathlib import Path

for myPath in Path.cwd().iterdir():
    print (myPath.name())
```

It gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "NameTest.py", line 4, in <module>
        print (myPath.name())
TypeError: 'str' is not callable
```

If I print the "myPath" object type, everything in the directory returns class pathlib.windowspath.

I'm using Python 3.4 on Windows 8 in the latest version of parallels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myPath.name` isn't callable, because it's an *attribute* of `str` type.
Try this instead:

```
for myPath in Path.cwd().iterdir():
    print(myPath.name)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I don't know why I didn't see that.

Comment: Had the same thing with `Path(your_path).parent`  --> `parent` and `name` are str types, and should not be called as function()

Answer (score 0):

@ David Maddox,
Dude, I made the same mistake you did. When I want to handle an absolute path: `'C:\\Users\\109_IR\\2023_06_15_09_43_53_078.jpg'` with `pathlib`'s `Path()`,I got the same Traceback error as you did.It turns out that we can put a `str` variable like `'C:\\Users\\109_IR\\2023_06_15_09_43_53_078.jpg'` in `Path()`.The reason for my error is that there is a variable named **Path** in front of my code.This causes an error when calling the `Path()` function in `pathlib`.This is obviously a simple mistake and hopefully no body else will make the same mistake as me